# NameError: name 'DeliveryOrder' is not defined

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

Here I am trying to call deliveryorder as ForeignKey into the PurchaseOrder table. Once I run makemigrations it shows the above error. Moreover, I can not write the PurchaseOrder definition after the DeliveryOrder because the DeliveryOrder table also holding PurchaseOrder as ForeignKey.

Purchase Order

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
   
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deliveryorder = models.ForeignKey(DeliveryOrder)
    po_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.part.partname
```

Delivery Order

```
class DeliveryOrder(models.Model):
    purchaseorder = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    do_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.do_quantity
```

Can suggest to me how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Python reads the `PurchaseOrder` class, it has not yet defined the `DeliveryOrder`, hence the `NameError`. Django has however a solution for this: you work with a string that contains the name of the model, or `'app_name.ModelName'` in case the model is in another app.

You thus can implement this with:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    # …
    deliveryorder = models.ForeignKey(
        'DeliveryOrder',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # …

class DeliveryOrder(models.Model):
    # …
    pass
```

Since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), it is mandatory to specify a value for the [**`on_delete=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete). The documentation lists the strategies about hat to do if the `DeliveryOrder` is removed with the `PurchaseOrder`s that refer to that field.